# MS Excel Find Specific Text at the End of Text String

Tags: excel, search, pattern-matching

With the use of a MS Excel Formula (Not VBA/Macros), I have a list of words ("verbs") located down `Column A2:A300`. I would like a formula that will search and extract only the ending letters that matches the search criteria located in `Column D2:D13`.

I currently have a MS Formula that closely does what I am looking for, but the issue is that it will identify any word within the cell that contains the specific text at any location (see formula below).

EXAMPLE:  Find the past tense letter "ed" at the end of the word "Acceded", this formula works, but also returns "ed" if the word is only "Accede", because it found the letters within the text (???ed?) and not at the end of the text string.

CURRENT FORMULA (Located in `B2`):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$300,MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$300,A2)),-1,1)*(ROW($D$2:$D$300)-ROW($D$2)+1))),"None")
```

I've highlighted words in "Red" to reflect the error and solution, I'm trying to resolve if possible with a formula.

[image]

SAMPLE OUTPUT RESULTS

[image]

Comment: This will be much easier via VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cell B2 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$13,MATCH(1,INDEX(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$D$2:$D$13),),0)),"None")
```

Adjust the D2:D13 range as needed to be your "Search Tense" list in column D.  Make certain there are no blanks in the column D list.

Comment: @findwindow that is correct, which is the intent and purpose of this formula, because that is specifically what the OP is asking for.  It should ONLY match if the matching text is at the end of the string.

Comment: I mean, it failed with accede.

Comment: It should fail with accede, that was specifically stated in the original question.

Comment: Nevermind, it's _my_ fault. I didn't change A2. Impressive.

Comment: This conversation actually explains a lot about your logic ^_^;

Comment: Tigeravatar, thank you very much... Your provided formula works and absolutely the solution I was looking for..  - Thanks a ton.

Comment: Tigeravatar, I would like to know, if you're able to do the exact same thing, but a reverse formula.  To extract only the words LEFT of the matching "Search Tense" D2:D13?

Comment: Tigeravatar, I would like to know, if you're able to do the exact same thing, but a reverse formula.  To extract only the words LEFT of the matching "Search Tense" D2:D13?  I cannot use the LEFT formula to achieve this, as with my current post, the left formula will extract any word left containing "ed" regardless of its location.  (Example: Acceded returns "Acc", when applying: =LEFT(AA2, SEARCH("ed",AA2,1)-1).